# How to assign new users different text files

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, bufferedreader, filereader

The program that I am working on asks the user if they are a new user or not and if the user is a new user you have to assign their very own txt file for their personalized music database. The txt file should be labelled with the user's name. I tried to use an `int` variable to label the txt file because the number of users is unknown. This is what I've done so far:

```
System.out.println ("Are you a new user?(y/n)");

response = (stdin.readLine ());

if (response.equals ("Y"))
{
    System.out.println ("What is your name?");
    name [0] = (stdin.readLine ());

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("" + name + ".txt"));

    System.out.println ("How many songs would you like to enter?");
    number = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine ());

    for (int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++)
    {

        System.out.println ("What is the artist of the song you would like to add?");
        artist [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        System.out.println ("What is the genre of the song you would like to add?");
        genre [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        System.out.println ("What is the name of the song you would like to add?");
        songs [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        count++;
    }


    for (int i = 0 ; i < number + count ; i++)
    {
        writer.write ("" + artist [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write ("" + genre [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write ("" + songs [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
    }
    writer.close ();

}
else if (response.equals ("y"))
{
    System.out.println ("What is your name?");
    name [0] = (stdin.readLine ());

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("" + name + ".txt"));

    System.out.println ("How many songs would you like to enter?");
    number = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine ());

    for (int i = 0 ; i < number ; i++)
    {

        System.out.println ("What is the artist of the song you would like to add?");
        artist [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        System.out.println ("What is the genre of the song you would like to add?");
        genre [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        System.out.println ("What is the name of the song you would like to add?");
        songs [i] = (stdin.readLine ());
        count++;
    }


    for (int i = 0 ; i < number + count ; i++)
    {
        writer.write ("" + artist [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write ("" + genre [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
        writer.write ("" + songs [i] + "");
        writer.newLine ();
    }
    writer.close ();
}
```

Comment: Are all usernames unique?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Second that @EvanKnowles. Also, use try-catch for reading in user input to handle exceptions gracefully. Read up on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Comment: What is the issue here ?

Comment: What's the deal with all that copy&paste?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a new file for new users use like this

```
 File file = new File(name+ ".txt");

    if(! file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (file));
```

Also use

```
response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```

to avoid duplicate code